# Move deleted mails to another folder besides Gmail's trash

Tags: thunderbird, gmail, imap

I have set up a Gmail account with IMAP at Thunderbird (17.0.9). Everything so far works good. When I delete my mails the are moved under Gmail's Trash
But this is something I do not want to happen (since they last only 30 days in there!). I want to delete my mails and send them to another folder (label) name "MyTrash". So I changed the Trash by account settings > server settings > when i delete a message > move it to this folder : "MyTrash" .
Still though when I delete a message it keeps appearing under Gmail's Trash, Why is that?

I have been using this option for long (actually it works in another PC), but I wanted to make a fresh installation in my current PC.

Comment: Add a rule to move mail in trash to mytrash

Answer (score 0):

This option from Thunderbird is not working for GMail account because they use a special IMAP server.

More information here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=533140